# change node_modules directory when run command npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

i have my folder structure

```
folder1
   package.json
   src
     files
folder2
   package.json
   src
     files
folder3
   package.json
   src
     files
```

I would like that when I run the command to install packages, I create a folder with modules not in the same directory as package.json, but, for example, in the same directory above.
That is, I want the node_modules folder to be at the same level as the folder1, folder2 and folder3 folders.
I tried to use `npm config set prefix /mypath` but still didn’t figure out how to use it correctly.

Comment: Why? This seems to be breaking the very nature of keeping apps and their modules together. You can install modules globally (modules like ESLint, for example), but this doesn't seem like a very practical idea.